# I cant install Gnome Player

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, software-installation, gnome

I am using Lichee Pi Zero Development Board(Debian LXDE). My board(Lichee Pi) has not a wifi,so i can not dowloand Gnome Player. I dowloand Gnome.tar.gz file with use rasberry and then copy this file into the Debian SD Card. After the "tar -xzf file" command, gnome is seemed in file system. but not installed. how can install this player with use this folder?

[image: tar.gz package unboxing]

[image: gnome player folder]

I tried this <link: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/191390/how-to-use-sudo-command-to-install-tar-gz>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191390/how-to-use-sudo-command-to-install-tar-gz%3E)
but after the ./configure,An error occurred:
[image]

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you downloaded the source code which will need to be compiled and installed. If this is really what you want to do then you should follow the build instructions on the website.

However I don't think this is what your really want.
I suggest you download the .deb package for the right architecture.
Depending on which version of the Pi you are using.
Look for the gnome-mplayer package here:

[Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)

Then once you downloaded and copied the .deb file on your device you can run:

```
dpkg -i PACKAGE_NAME_HERE.deb
```

Comment: i try install debian file but there ara so much "libxxxx.armhf missing: assuming package has no files currently installed" error during installation. What is the problem? @proxx